# No method named len found for type <T as Trait>::Type in the current scope

Tags: generics, rust

I want to inform `VecLengthDirector` that `AbstractVecLengthBuider`'s associated type is always `[i32; n]` (n ∈ N). I wrote the following code:

```
struct VecLengthDirector<T> {
    builder: T,
}

impl<T> VecLengthDirector<T>
where
    T: AbstractVecLengthBuider,
{
    fn construct(&self) -> f64 {
        let s = self.builder.get_start_point();
        let e = self.builder.get_end_point();

        let mut sum: i32 = 0;
        for i in 0..s.len() {
            sum += (s[i] - e[i]).pow(2);
        }

        (sum as f64).sqrt()
    }
}

trait AbstractVecLengthBuider {
    type PointType;
    fn add_start_point(&mut self, point: Self::PointType);
    fn get_start_point(&self) -> Self::PointType;
    fn add_end_point(&mut self, point: Self::PointType);
    fn get_end_point(&self) -> Self::PointType;
}
```

And the errors reported.

```
error[E0599]: no method named `len` found for type `<T as AbstractVecLengthBuider>::PointType` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:14:23
   |
14 |         for i in 0..s.len() {
   |                       ^^^

error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `<T as AbstractVecLengthBuider>::PointType`
  --> src/main.rs:15:21
   |
15 |             sum += (s[i] - e[i]).pow(2);
   |                     ^^^^

error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `<T as AbstractVecLengthBuider>::PointType`
  --> src/main.rs:15:28
   |
15 |             sum += (s[i] - e[i]).pow(2);
   |                            ^^^^
```

Comment: Don't put "type" in the name of the type; it's redundant. `Point` will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quickfix**

You need to specify the kind of `PointType`. For example `T: AbstractVecLengthBuider<PointType = [i32]>>`. However, the size of `[i32]` is not known at compile time so you can replace it with `Vec<i32>`: `T: AbstractVecLengthBuider<PointType = Vec<i32>>`.

If you still want to be generic, you can constrain `PointType` to be borrowable as `[i32]`:

```
impl<T, P> VecLengthDirector<T>
where
    T: AbstractVecLengthBuider<PointType = P>,
    P: ::std::borrow::Borrow<[i32]>,
{
    fn construct(&self) -> f64 {
        let s = self.builder.get_start_point().borrow();
        let e = self.builder.get_end_point().borrow();
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is not idiomatic Rust.

**Idiomatic Rust way**

Your loop can be rewritten to more idiomatic Rust:

```
s.iter()
    .zip(e.iter())
    .map(|(se, ee)| (se - ee).pow(2) as f64)
    .sum()
```

Then you just need to constrain `PointType` to be iterable over `i32`:

```
impl<T, P> VecLengthDirector<T>
where
    T: AbstractVecLengthBuider<PointType = P>,
    P: ::std::iter::IntoIterator<Item = i32>,
{
    fn construct(&self) -> f64 {
        let s = self.builder.get_start_point();
        let e = self.builder.get_end_point();

        s.into_iter()
            .zip(e.into_iter())
            .map(|(se, ee)| (se - ee).pow(2) as f64)
            .sum::<f64>()
            .sqrt()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to inform `VecLengthDirector` that `AbstractVecLengthBuider`'s Associated Type is always `[i32; n]` (n ∈ N).

You can't.  If you want to use a particular operation on an associated type, you need to use one or more trait constraints.

For example, indexing requires an implementation of the [`Index`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) trait.

There is no trait that includes `<[_]>::len`.  That said, you can write one that should cover most relevant cases by abusing iterators:

```
pub trait Length {
    fn len(self) -> usize;
}

impl<'a, T> Length for &'a T
where
    &'a T: IntoIterator,
    <&'a T as IntoIterator>::IntoIter: ::std::iter::ExactSizeIterator,
{
    fn len(self) -> usize {
        self.into_iter().len()
    }
}

pub trait RefLength {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
}

impl<T> RefLength for T
where
    for<'a> &'a T: Length,
{
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        Length::len(self)
    }
}
```

You could then use something like `type PointType: Index<usize> + RefLength;` in the trait definition.